# Import from file having line breaks

Tags: import, db2

How to import data from a export file having the line breaks in a column.

for example i have a table with column as remarks, when the user entered the remarks from frontend of application it allowed the line breaks and the same data is stored in the table. but when export is taken and tried  to import to other table the import failed due to line breaks.

Comment: What version of DB2?  What does your import command look like?  What do your _line breaks_ look like?  Should they be "encoded" - not all platforms encode line breaks the same way.

Comment: DB2 version is 9.5. The import looks likes this `import from file.del of del modified by coldel^ insert into inserttable`.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using the `IMPORT` or `LOAD` utilities to load data into DB2 for Linux, UNIX and Windows:

If your character fields are properly quoted (i.e. they have `"` at the beginning and end of each character field in the file), then you can use the `DELPRIORITYCHAR` [file-type modifier](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html#r0008304__d63360e2030):

```
import from yourfile.csv 
   of del modified by delprioritychar
   insert into yourtable
```

This instructs the `IMPORT` and `LOAD` utilities to prioritize the character delimiter (`"`) over the record delimiter (i.e. newline).

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest approach would be to replace the line break characters with something else, e.g. the escape sequences `\n`, then, if needed, replace them back after importing.

Comment: i really mot sure whethaer **\n** will work